# Pivot unique values from Column B to a new column after grouping Column A

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
COL_A   COL_B
1   a
1   b
2   a
2   b
3   a
3   b
4   c
4   d
5   c
5   d
```

and I'm attempting to group the values in COL_A and pivot the unique values in COL_B to a new column

```
COL_A   COL_B   COL_C
1   a   b
2   a   b
3   a   b
4   c   d
5   c   d
```

I've tried a bunch of different techniques with df.groupby and df.pivot but I can't seem to get my desired results.

Comment: Does each unique `COL_A` value always occur exactly twice?

Comment: In this case yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since each unique `COL_A` value always occurs exactly twice, you can reshape your series and feed to the `pd.DataFrame` constructor:

```
df = df.sort_values('COL_A')

arr = df['COL_B'].values.reshape(-1, 2)

res = pd.DataFrame({'COL_A': df['COL_A'].unique(),
                    'COL_B': arr[:, 0],
                    'COL_C': arr[:, 1]})

print(res)

   COL_A COL_B COL_C
0      1     a     b
1      2     a     b
2      3     a     b
3      4     c     d
4      5     c     d
```